# How to compare if a timestamptz date equal a timestamptz date in Javascript/Postgresql

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, timestamp

I got a date in this format when i get my data in my postgresql database like that : 2022-02-20 00:37:11.337937+00

But when i get this from my javascript code i get this result instead : 2022-02-20T00:37:15.279Z

How can i compare this date since 2022-02-20T00:37:15.279Z is cut with a 'Z' at the end.
I try to compare strictly exazctly this date : 2022-02-20 00:37:11.337937+00 in my JS backend code.

EDIT:
In fact, i can have an array of waht i want, but i can't get value message, and others value in my database.
This is the request i have, but i can't get the message property:

```
SELECT ID, MAX(lastmsg) FROM 
(   SELECT m.receiver AS ID, MAX(m.created_at) as lastmsg FROM message m
WHERE m.sender = '1'
GROUP BY m.receiver
UNION
SELECT m.sender AS ID, MAX(m.created_at) as lastmsg FROM message m
WHERE m.receiver = '1'
GROUP BY m.sender
) as table2 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY max LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

I found this solution from another post, but i don't know how to get message field, if i change that i have to add it to the GROUP bY but then my result is not the result expected

I tried something like that, but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (sender, receiver)
          sender, receiver, message AS msg, created_at AS created_at
    FROM message
    WHERE sender = '1' OR receiver = '1'
    ORDER BY sender, receiver, created_at
) f
```

I got duplicated value with that

Edit 2:
I'm running version 12.2 of Postgresql on a Debian

Comment: aside from the missing `T` (noted in the [postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) *'ISO 8601 specifies the use of uppercase letter T to separate the date and time. PostgreSQL accepts that format on input, but on output it uses a space rather than T...'*) they are both valid ISO 8601 date strings and can be compared by converting them to javascript Date objects.

Comment: But from your comment on the answer below it looks like you should just filter the result in the query [Row with latest timestamp](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108267/row-with-latest-timestamp)

Comment: The problem is, i want aalmost the same thing, but i want all result like where field1 = 1 or field2 = 1.
But for the context, i have a chat system, i want to get all last message for each conversations.
But i want the first value with the most recent timestamps sender = 1 or receiver = 1 i want just the last value for each different sender and receiver .
Do you see what i mean ?

Comment: You can just add a `when` clause? You'll have to post more details about your code/query for concrete help.

Comment: I have a table of message, where you have an id, a message and 2 user's id, one sender and one receiver.
When you have a conversation between 2 users, with multiple messages in the same conversations you will have multiple time the same user as the sender and receiver.
So for a given user, you have multiple convversations.
So i want only the last message of all conversations where the user id is always id = 1 for example

Comment: I did this, based on your exemple:
SELECT *
FROM message 
WHERE sender = '1' OR receiver = '1'
ORDER BY created_at DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1;
He will return the last message for the contact where user contact id = 2
But not the other users for id = 3, 4, 5 etc..

Comment: I edited the post with the solution i have, and from where i got my array.
BUt for me i could directly get other fields from my table, but i don't know how

Comment: As always, start with your Postgres version and table definition. You are mixing `timestamp`, `timestamptz` and `date` freely. Also, explain your objective more clearly, show a minimal example and the expected result.  Once the task is clear, the solution will be simple.

Comment: I just edited my post before you comment, the story with the timestamptz was a second solution i tried.

Comment: I took the array given by my request who give me the result expected for getting the conversations with the first message.
And iterate on this array to request each data who match my timestamptz date.
But date format in my database and the date format is not the same, so i can't compare if both date are equal

Comment: Or first solution it would be to get every data i want directly in my request, but i don't know how, i'm stuck

Answer (score 0):

You cannot compare the two dates with timestamps. First, you should convert the timestamp into a date format (DD/MM/YY) before executing your query.
You can also use the below method as well.

```
datetime: {
        [Op.gte]: moment(req.body.datetime).startOf('day'),
        [Op.lte]: moment(req.body.datetime).endOf('day'),
      },
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the problem is, i need to compare 2 dates from my database with the timestamptz.
Because i want to get from my database a list of data with 2 specifics id relations who can be duplicated multiple time.
If this id is on my field1 or field2 the i want to get the last date with the most recent timestamptz